# Cloudfront redirect behavior based on query string

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am using CloudFront on AWS and am trying to figure out if it is possible to redirect to a different origin based on a query string parameter, instead of the traditional path pattern.

My guess is no, because I try to do so I get the following error message
[image]

Since a `=` sign is not allowed in the path pattern, it makes it impossible to redirect based on query parameter.

I think this would be useful for a scenario where you only want to render a portion of your site based on that parameter. Say you only want `partner A` to see a certain feature temporarily, instead of putting this in your code, you could put it in your CLoudFront config.

`https://mywebsite.com/exclusive/feature?partner=A`

Comment: did u use lambda@edge or did you just add partner=A in behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can have that logic inside your actual **viewer request** CF function:

```
function handler(event) {
  var paramName = 'partner';
  var paramValue = event.request.querystring[paramName];
  if (!!paramValue && paramValue.value === 'Partner A') {
      return {
          statusCode: 302,
          statusDescription: 'Found',
          headers: {
              'locaton': {'value': 'new location goes here'}
          };
  }
  return request;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible simply altering the behavior. Instead, you need to use a Lambda@Edge to write a custom code to do this.

For more information refer [Lambda@Edge Example Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html).

You can implement this with a combination of Adding a Header Based on a Query String Parameter and Content-Based Dynamic Origin Selection examples.